# What would one call a list of people to be killed?

Tags: word-request

I know this sounds kinda morbid, but is there an english word for a list of people who are to be killed? Let's say, a hitman gets a list of targets, what would he call it? My first though was "hitlist", but I'm not really sure if this is an actual commonly used word or just a made-up term (there's a movie or something called *The Hit List*) that derivated from "hitman" as a synonym for "killer" ...

Comment: I don't know, but in my imagination the assassin keeps things non-specific: "He's on **my list**."

Comment: I believe "hit list" would be most recognizable term.

Comment: I looked 'hit list' up in two online dictionaries, including [this one](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hit-list).

Comment: If you are writing fiction, have fun with it. The Doomed. The Damned.The Select. The Unfortunate. The Chosen Ones. My *Friends* The Walking Dead...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Hit list' is generally the colloquial term, though I've seen things like 'Kill On Sight' (KOS) list used in certain online games.

Comment: A _hit_ is indeed a common slang for _a kill_, hence the _hit man_ and the _hit list_, or even _take out a hit on someone_.

Comment: @oerkelens I don't know about "take out a hit" but I've definitely heard "carry out a hit".

Answer (score 1):

"Hitlist" is probably the most commonly used word for this, but I just want to point out that there's no single definitive answer. You will end up having to make up some phrase for it, and that phrase will depend highly on context. For example, it would be quite weird to describe a list of prisoners on death row as a "hitlist," unless you were trying to make a political statement about the death penalty. For death row specifically, I might say something like "list of death row inmates."

Comment: There's also "proscription list," which implies it's being done by someone in a position of political power: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proscription